# How to trigger an aJax call on page load

Tags: javascript, wordpress, autoload

This is the function which runs on click by default in somefile of wordpress

```
jQuery( function($) {

        var $container = $('.grid');

        $('.filters-button-group').on( 'click', 'button', function() {
            var filterValue = $( this ).attr('data-filter');
            var filterCategory = $( this ).attr('data-filter-category');
            var getQuery = env.AJAX+'?action=get_events&tribe_event_category='+filterValue

            $.ajax({
                cache : false,
                url: getQuery,
                success: function(data){
                    $container.html( data.results )
                }
            });

        });


    }(jQuery))
```

This is the script i am trying to hit in another file of wordpress

```
jQuery( function($) {
    $('.filters-button-group .autoTrigger').trigger('click'); 

}(jQuery))
```

Button is triggered but it dosn't perform the functionality which runs after clicking the button.

Comment: have you included a reference to another file? for example `<script src="anotherfile.js"></script>`

Comment: What is the value of `env.AJAX`?